# AJAX Response Size Limit

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, size

I am using AJAX to asynchronously call a PHP script that returns a large serialized array of JSON objects (about 75kbs or 80k characters).  Every time I try and return it it hits a 3000 character limit.  Is there a maximum size set anywhere on servers or within jQuery's ajax implementation?

EDIT:  the 3'000 limit is a Chrome limit, FF has a 10'000 character limit and Safari has no limit.  I'm guessing there is no fix for this apart from changing my code to split/lessen the return data.

Comment: Similar: http://stackoverflow.com/q/1151987/1026459

Comment: That's ASP though - I saw that when searching ...

Comment: [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/898477/ajax-request-browser-limit) may shed some light. The accepted answer states that it's the JSON array's _depth_ that matters, not it's size. When you view your 3k char response, is it cut off at the beginning of an array/object, or in a random place?

Comment: Is the error logical or explicit?

Comment: It returns the beginning of the expected return value and then there's an ellipsis bang in the middle and then it returns the end of the expected return value.

Comment: @JamWaffles - also I'm only returning an array of JSON serialized as plain text so I guess it shouldn't really be reading it as a JSON.

Answer (score 1):

You can split your JSON and get with $.ajax part by part

I made an example for you

Html side :

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
    <script src="jquery.js"></script>
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {

        window.result_json = {};

       $.get("x.php?part=size",function(data){
          var count = data;
          for (var i = 0; i <= count; i++) {
            $.ajax({
              dataType: "json",
              url: "x.php",
              async: false,
              data: "part="+i,
              success: function(data){
                $.extend(window.result_json,data);
              }
            });
          };
          console.log(window.result_json);
       });
    });
</script>
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

PHP side (file name is x.php) :

```
<?php
if(isset($_GET['part'])){

    function send_part_of_array($array,$part,$moo){
        echo json_encode(array_slice($array, $part * $moo,$moo,true),JSON_FORCE_OBJECT);
    }
    $max_of_one = 3;
    $a = array("a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j");

    if($_GET['part'] == 'size'){
        echo round(count($a) / $max_of_one);
    }else{
        send_part_of_array($a,$_GET['part'],$max_of_one);
    }

}
?>
```

Firstly with `$.get` (part=size), check how many slices.

Secondly with `$.ajax`(part=(int)PART-NUMBER) , in for loop get the parts of JSON one by one

Lastly with `$.extend` in for loop marge new getting JSON and old JSON elements in `window.result_json`

**NOTE:  `$max_of_one` variable determine how many slices to post.**