# jQuery ajax crashes chrome on HTTP 206 (Partial content)

Tags: jquery, ajax, http, google-chrome, crash

This thing has been bugging me for some time now and I can't find a reason/solution on the Web so far. Here is the setup:

I have a fat JS client running on a browser, firing up search requests into an internal system. Those requests are just GET's, nothing special. They return a URL where the search results will be put into once they are available.

I then poll the given URL for results (from time to time, say every 5 minutes) and process the data to be presented to user. That URL points to a gzipped results file which is just a plain text (ASCII).

Now... the search results are often within a few hundred lines of text, but occasionally there will be hundreds of thousands of lines of text, at times 7-10MB worth of text (after unzipping). And that's where the browser shows the sad-tab page.

(No need to point out the security issues with this approach, they are numerous and highly potent).

Nothing special there - just calling a

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/cgi-bin/ajax_gz.cgi',
    type: 'POST',
    data: 'curl -k "' + self.url_res + '"',
    dataType: 'html',
    success: function (_data, _status, _xhr) {
        self.update_result(_data, _status, _xhr);
    },
    error: function (_xhr, _status, _error) {
        self.set_status(Status.ACK);
    },
    timeout: 5 * ONE_MINUTE
});
```

where the `ajax_gz.cgi` is nothing more elaborate than a simple dumb proxy (to allow my JS to pull data from a different domain by relaying the `curl` requests):

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Content-type: text/html"
echo "Content-encoding: gzip"
echo ""
/bin/bash
```

the return is indeed a gzipped HTML, so I'm setting the header for that. I suppose I could update the headers in ajax()'s config, but this seemed to be a simpler approach.

The `success` or `error` functions never get called and the timeout (5 minutes) is also not a problem - it's all on LAN and the whole transfer takes less than half a minute.

I can open that URL in a tab with no problems at all, and it shows me the unzipped plan ASCII text. But when retrieving data with jQuery's ajax() I'm facing a sad-tab page (almost every time, but only for "Partial content" HTTP 206 responses).

What am I missing? Trying to "step through" in JS debugger doesn't help much as all I get is a sudden sad-tab and the debugging session is then killed.

**Update:** Stepping through the jQuery's code and stopping at the `readyState===4`'s function I was able to catch the response. It was `HTTP 200` with the full text (from the opening `<html>` tag all the way to the closing one with 108K lines in-between in a single `<pre>` tag).
Once I got that response and tried to "expand" the `this` value I got a sad-tab page

Comment: Do other browsers besides Chrome perform okay?

Comment: Out of interest, have you tried using the latest version of jQuery? using .done(), .fail() and .complete() instead of .success() and .error(). Also can you simulate it on your dev before trying the cross domain?

Comment: Once you stopped at the readyState == 4 statement, were you able to step through until the crash? What was the last line you were able to execute?

Comment: @jsha - just downloading the target .gz file in a Chrome tab crashes the browser

Comment: @apsillers - I didn't try in IE or FF, but Safari crashes

Answer (score 0):

I think that you are running into a Chrome memory limitation. Accoding to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10165543/ajax-response-size-limit) chrome might have a limitation of 3000 characters for AJAX calls.

As you've noticed the developer tools shows it all, but when reading it to be returned to jQuery it hits some form of ceiling. Can you try limiting your response to under that limit to see if it works? Perhaps try with another browser?

If this is the issue, you could try returning the results in parts. A few parts returned might get around the limitation.

Comment: That code has definitely parsed (successfully) way over 3K chars. I've seen it work with as much as 3M chars.

I don't control the server side so changing what it returns is out of question for me.

Answer (score 0):

Since your bash proxy (yikes!) doesn't do any gzipping, and curl normally decompresses anything it receives with Content-Encoding: gzip, I'm assuming the response from your internal server is coming back gzipped, but without the Content-Encoding header present.

It sounds like your curl script is getting a 206 from your internal server, right? That's a little odd, since servers should only return 206 in response to a Range header. However, taken that as a given, you'll be getting a partial response of gzipped content and passing it along to Chrome as a 200. This shouldn't crash Chrome, of course, but there could be a bug in there.

Perhaps try unzipping :

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Content-type: text/html"
echo ""
curl -k "`cat`" | gunzip
```

You would also want to change your Ajax data source:

```
data: self.url_res,
```

If that fails, try capturing full headers from curl using -i for further debugging.

Comment: Good guess, but not entirely correct. I am using a special gzip-friendly version of that script, that does put a proper Content-type header. `curl` does *not* automatically un-gzip the returned data though.